# proper syntax for stylus mixin using transform translate() or other 2 part rules

Tags: mixins, stylus

In stylus, when trying to make mixins with transform translate() - or any other multipart rules...

I get: "Maximum stylus call stack size exceeded at "

```
scale(n)
    transform scale(n)

scale()
    transform scale(arguments)
```

(tried a bunch of stuff...)

[Here is an example CodePen](http://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/DlfzI)

Answer (score 1):

Yep, if you're trying to produce the value with the same function as the one you're calling, you should output it literally, like this:

```
scale(n)
  transform 'scale(%s)' % n
```

This way it would output the ident entity and won't call the `scale` function, so there won't be any infinite loops.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I found. I had made mixins for each, but I forgot that they override each other. So, this seems like the best option for me.

```
transform(value)
  transform: value

.thing
  background red
  width 3rem
  height 3rem
  transform( translate(20%,20%) scale(1.2) rotate(98deg) )
```

Answer (score 0):

if you define your mixin func name with a builtin css method, you may get this error. for example:

```
rotate($angular)               // mixin func name
  transform rotate($angular)   // rotate is a builtin css method, but stylus treats this "rotate" as a mixin usage, which makes a dead loop.
```